# Can't access functions from package installed with npm

Tags: vuejs2, tinymce, vue-component

I'm trying to access the different methods from tinyMCE, but it can't find get, setContent or insertContent. Anyone got any ideas how I can access these? The following code is a copy from their documentation.

Here is my code so far:

App.vue:

```js
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <Editor id="test"></Editor>
        <button @click="insertData">Test</button>
      </div>

    </template>

    <script>


    export default {

      name: 'App',
      components: {
        Editor
      },
      methods: {
          insertData: function () {
            Editor.get("test").setContent("This is a test.")
          }
      }
    }
    </script>

    <style>
    #app {
      font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      text-align: center;
      color: #2c3e50;
      margin-top: 60px;
    }
    </style>
```

main.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
// es modulesc
var commonjsrequire = require('commonjs-require');
// NOTE: default needed after require
var Editor = require('@tinymce/tinymce-vue').default;

Vue.component('Editor',
    () => import('@tinymce/tinymce-vue')
);

new Vue({
  render: function (h) { return h(App) },
}).$mount('#app')
```

Comment: but where have you registered `Editor` component globally?, i think you have too

Comment: Is it correct now? Please see edit. Still no difference though

Comment: also show us the error you given

Comment: There are none, I just can't access the methods thats supposed to be provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functions you are after are tied to the `tinymce` global object.  While you define an `Editor` component in the context of the application the actual API calls for TinyMCE are part of the `tinymce` global object.

For example:

```
tinymce.get("test").setContent("<p>This is a test.</p>")
```